Is my magic enough to keep a person without skin alive for a month?
A specific ritual conducted by mages called the Skinless removes their entire skin as a consequence. To prepare for this, they hire a Blood Mage specialized in human biology, a Destruction Mage specialized in extreme small-scale destruction, and a Fire Mage specialized in heat manipulation. More mages could be hired to work in shifts if need be.
The Blood Mage ensures that the Skinless doesn't die of blood loss and shock by meticulously manipulating any displaced blood and other bodily fluids of the Skinless. The Destruction Mage destroys any possible bacteria or other contaminants from any and every potential source with a limit of 0.001 micrometer that could cause a fatal infection. The Fire Mage vibrates the air around the Skinless to adjust temperatures to prevent death to hypothermia. All the mages fine-tune their spells and adjust the degree of their magic depending on the circumstances. For a month, they will be attended by the three hired mages until the ritual's backlash subsides and they can finally hire a healing mage.
The Skinless will be floating as a form of locomotion to not exacerbate their injuries. Accompanying this, they remain within their homes doing minimal actions. They will be fed through IV drips.
What have I missed in my magic keeping the Skinless alive for a month?

There was a patient that was exposed to a violent burst of gamma radiation, I wanna say it was Chernobyl, that volunteered to be kept alive for as long as possible, even thought he knew he was dead, just so they could study the effects of radiation on a patient. It was weeks of grueling misery, but you could use it as a resource for your world building

Found it, it was japan: https://allthatsinteresting.com/hisashi-ouchi

Also, I was wrong, he was kept alive against his will.

Is the question you're trying to ask this... "As the skin of a human being is removed, and after the skin has been removed, there will be consequences leading to the human's death. I know about (1) blood loss and shock, (2) bacteria, disease and contaminants, and (3) hypothermia. I am not considering the psychological consequences in this question. Are there other enviornmental consequences that could lead to death that should be protected against?" I assume there will come a time when you no longer care about these conditions as the magic will resolve them.

@JBH Yes, that's what I intended

Are the 3 specialist mages able to avoid any need for sleep during the entire month too?  What is the patient/victim doing during the month - bed rest, in an induced coma or moving about and living "normally"?

@KerrAvon2055 Added it in

A thought - as long as you're keeping them alive with magic, what stops you from handwaving it all by saying "a team of mages" without being too specific about most of them? If I'm a reader, I probably don't want to know the gory details of who does what, and that way you avoid the question "but what about..."

Side note: ewww.

Minor question that's born completely out of interest - what's the ritual for?

@Daemons Masochism

@Dmyt interesting, interesting…. If I was one I’d probably go through that ritual too… in the name of questionable scientific cult practices!

how much of the skin, the epidermis, the dermis, all the way to the hypodermis, just the stratum corneum, each has very diffrent answer.

Magic is magic, if you say it's capable of doing this then it is. That's the beauty of it and the problem with it.

Cool idea. Thanks for the nightmare fuel!

Possibly Survivable
I'd disagree with the selected answer. The closest analogy we have for this are massive burns. Burns involve massive, massive trauma alongside them. Swelling, intense pain, damage to other tissues, huge amounts of fluid in the wrong places, massive inflammation responses. If you're talking a relatively untraumatic (at least, on a physical level, this sounds psychologically scarring for all involved) removal of skin, then I think you up the survival chances hugely.
Past the initial trauma, the big problem, for burn patients, are infection, which has been solved for, shock, which seems to have been solved for, and temperature regulation, which seems to have been partially solved for. This is going to be pretty unpleasant, but there'd be ways to keep the person alive.
We're not incredibly far off the point where medical science would make this survivable in a modern setting - a quick google shows the most severe survived burn is a second degree, 95% coverage burn, so affecting 2 skin layers rather than all 3. Again, this is with a burn, with massive, massive inflammation.
However, let's make this work properly. I'd up your mage quotient. I'd hire a water mage, and essentially surround the patient in a thin bubble of sterile, isotonic water, with the blood mage artificially keeping their blood oxygenated, and removing waste gases. This would allow some cooling (allow some of the bubble to evaporate), and be more comfortable, as the patient wouldn't be touching any surfaces directly, but instead "floating". It would also reduce any damage due to pressure on the massive, all body wound, another concern with burn patients.
My mage schedule, then, would be:

Healing mage: sedates person, removes skin in a undamaging manner
Blood mage: stops bleeding, sterilizes area
Water mage: surrounds patient in layer of water, and regulates temperature artificially
Blood mage: handles blood oxygenation artificially, or Water mage: supplies oxygenated water to lungs
Healing mage: keeps patient unconscious for month

After 1 month:

Healing mage: regrows skin
Plague Wizard: replaces skin flora (beneficial bacteria, mites, etc) - complete removal of these are likely to lead to new infections.
Water mage: removes water bubble, and water from lungs.

I think they'd be fine! I mean, as long as they're kept unconscious, and in the equivalent of a mage ICU for a month, they'd probably live. Don't let the naysayers win! Get some skin in the game! Or at least, someone's skin.

For the breathing aspect, some experiments with liquid breathing have been undertaken in the past. While the breathing worked, all of the test subjects died a few days later (breathing air again), presumably because the breathing liquid washed out something essential from the lungs.

@And I know we've got systems that work in animal models, but the main issues (gas exchange, etc) seem to be solved with the kind of magic (microscopic level control over your element) that OP seems to be suggesting. There's not a real need to fill the lungs with water though, OP's water mages could leave a breathing tube.

I also thought it might be possible, given mages with control over microscopic aspects of the body, to just do a month of freezing the person - if a blood mage can remove microbes, a healing mage can presumably stitch together all the damage from ice puncturing the cells.

Dead
The skin has many uses. It is called 'the largest organ of the body' for a reason. You've covered a few and a half. They'll not be cold. They'll not be sick from bacteria and viruses (debatable, but let's say it's true). They'll not die from initial shock and blood loss.
The skin regulates heat. If anything happens, like a warm day, they'll not be able to cool down. They'll die.
Skin removes some waste products. I do not know the exact extent, but it is safe to say that a month of not excreting such wastes is not healthy, possibly deadly. It could lead to a process where (benevolent) bacteria and viruses that are already in the body start growing uncontrollably, which is purged by the destruction mage, essentially eroding the body.
They'll mot get vitamin D from the skin. A minor inconvenience.
Without skin you'll lose much of your senses. There are nerves and the like lower, but it is still an important part of proprioception, knowing where your body parts are. There is a good chance people will lose most, if not all control of the limbs. Actions can be done unwittingly with destructive and still painful effects. Something like the feeling of an itchy nose (phantom feeling, as theres no skin), can lead to poking your eye out or raking the skin uncontrollably.
Though an alternative can equally be true. It depends on where you stop. Many nerve endings might be exposed, leading to continuous, excruciating pain. Most probably you would still lose proprioception,making it an extremely hazardous condition for the affected.
There would also be an overall metabolic disruption, which is to say it can vary from person to person from bad to dead.
This all can lead to extreme stress, which can kill or disable someone for a long time.
There are many unknowns, but in general I would say there is a very large chance of death. If the person survives they could have permanent physical damage as well as severe trauma. Get more mages to fix it, or else you'll have a horrible execution thing with low chances of survival. I wouldn't necessarily call the survivors lucky.

As long as you're using magic, you can handwave any of these problems as much as you want, but they might even be a feature rather than a bug. If the operation is only successful for 1 in 10, with half dying and the rest permanently disabled, it raises the stakes for the Skinless a lot.

@user111403 magic solving everything is always striking me as an easy way out, that often isn't even plausible. If magic can solve everything, there is no need for conflict. Without conflict, you can't make stories. The question has clear restrictions. We know the mages and the spells. Is it enough to keep a skinless alive or not. It could be a wanted side effect that they die. That is true.

sure, too much magic-handwave fixes everything can be boring, but it seems to be what the OP needs here. The mages need to do something that should obviously kill them, and survive it using magic. I think that trying to go into too much detail may be a mistake.

UV
UV is invisible and quite harmful to deeper tissues. Skin stops it so they are not used to being exposed to it. None of your mages seem to be capable of stopping or controlling it. But well, just make skinless stay inside for a month and they should be good to go. I don't think they would like to show themselves outside anyway. Although I am not familiar with your world, maybe it would be the biggest flex due to amount of resources and connections it probably requires.

Evaporative water loss
Aside from losing fluids through bleeding, EWL is a significant issue without your skin and its lipid membranes helping to keep all your body moisture from evaporating. Notably this is a separate effect from all the fluids you lose from bleeding.
So you need to add a water mage who can inhibit the rate of evaporation, or, ideally, you should cover the person with something to keep their moisture in. Pig skin is a classic low impact option, and with your destruction mage to keep out infection, it will be relatively safe.

Wouldn't the IV drips cover that?

@toolforger Not normal ones, you'd need a large bore needle in the jugular just for hydration, then more normal IVs for nutrient drips.

Very Dead.
Skin is not purely external: your mouth lining, throat, stomach, intestines, and bladder are all made of skin cells.
If you remove someone's entire skin, the first problem is that they can't breathe anymore because there is no throat to channel air into their lungs. If you solve that then there is the fact that their stomach acid and digestive enzymes are going to dissolve most of the unremoved contents of their abdominal cavity. If they were horizontal during the removal then their lungs and heart are going to be affected; if not then it's "only" their liver, spleen, pancreas, kidneys and abdominal muscles in the firing line.
Then you have to deal with their gut contents: they're highly toxic and full of bacteria good and bad; septic shock is a given with a puncture let alone dumping the whole contents onto defenseless muscle tissue and blood vessels. The bacteria appear to be treatable by the destruction mage but the chemical toxicity of the material isn't, and that's an ongoing issue for the whole month. The body is going to keep digesting in certain particulars even without a gut. There are major ducts, again made from skin tissue dedicated to dumping toxic byproducts from the liver into the gut and the bladder is a dedicated organ for removing waste products from the kidneys in water.
The lymph system will also be compromised; this means the removal of working toxins from the major muscles is reduced - probably not fatal by itself but it won't help.

That's just wrong. The internal lining is NOT skin. It's called mucosa and is very different from skin

@Ivo Okay, that doesn't line up with what I was told when discussing skin, as an organ, live and learn.
